# Asp.Net CodeFirst How can i navigate between 3 models?

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, navigation-properties

I have 3 models in my project:

1. Category
2. Marka
3. Product

And I need to fill the **Category** dropdown with **Marka** options, like when you click on TV category and TV brands show up.

Here is my controller:

```
public ActionResult LoadMarkas(int CategoryId)
{
    return (_Contex.Markas.Where(m =>m.Products.CategoryId == CategoryId));
}
```

Sorry for bad English

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Please include sources of your model classes.